# MySQL query for multiple tables being secondary tables multiple items?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query where I currently get information from 2 tables like this:

```
SELECT g.name 
FROM site_access b 
    JOIN groups g 
        ON b.group_id = g.id 
WHERE b.site_id = 1 
ORDER BY g.status ASC
```

Now I wanted to have another table with this query but this one table would return more then 1 row is that possible at all ?

All I could make was it pull 1 row from that table, the field I want is a string field and it is ok to join the result with a separator too as long as all the matchs can be pulled together in this query.

**If you need more information about the tables or anything feel free to say I didnt think it would be needed as this is mostly an example of how to pull multiple rows from a join/select query.**

UPDATE of what the above query would result:

```
Admin
Member
Banned
```

Now with my 3rd table each access have commands they are allowed to use so this 3rd table would list what commands each one has access to, example:

```
Admin - add, del, announce
Member - find
Banned - none
```

UPDATE2:

- site_access

  ```
  site_id
  group_id
  ```
- groups

  ```
  id
  name
  status
  ```
- groups_commands

  ```
  group_id
  command_id
  ```
- commands

  ```
  id
  name
  ```

Comment: Are you saying you want all the column values returned by the newly joined table [concatenated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) into a single row?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli wether it needs to be joinned or not I wanted to know wether it is possible to retrive all the rows from a 3rd join table in the above query. Above query alone will give me 8 rows and each of those 8 rows will have X rows from the 3rd join in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT g.name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.command) AS commands
FROM site_access b 
    JOIN groups g 
        ON b.group_id = g.id 
    JOIN groups_commands gc
        ON g.id = gc.group_id
    JOIN commands c
        ON gc.command_id = c.id
WHERE b.site_id = 1 
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER BY g.status ASC
```

Comment: Stefanelli, thanks I just forgot a small thing the I have groups_commands where i have the relation from group_id to the command_id and from there I pull up the string so it is actually 2 tables so I could use a INNER JOIN on top of the commands join right ?

Comment: @Prix: Right. I'll adjust the answer to reflect this.

Comment: thank you very much I have also updated my question with a sample of the tables, Really appreciate your help, I am still not as good with all this JOIN, LEFT, RIGHT INNER stuff.

Comment: Your query works wonderfully I was under the impression I would have to do more like an Inner select, or that there was a way to do a inner join of an previous join but you did it with just JOIN ;)