# CONCAT only returns rows that are not null

Tags: mysql, sql, null, concatenation

I have searched in a few topics for how to resolve this issue I am having with a query that uses CONCAT but yet must return the groups even if the concat is null and I have found 2 solutions that doesnt work.

First solution was to use ISNULL:

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'
```

Second was to use IFNULL which works partially, it does find which are not null but yet doesnt print the null ones.

Here is the query:

```
  SELECT g.name, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c.name),'') AS commands
    FROM site_access b
    JOIN groups g ON b.group_id = g.id
    JOIN group_commands gc ON g.id = gc.group_id
    JOIN commands c ON gc.command_id = c.id
   WHERE b.site_id = 1
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER BY g.status ASC
```

I have 8 site_access, 8 groups and currently registered and only 2 commands that are assigned to group 1 and group 2, what currently happens is that it does print these 2 groups but ignore all the rest because they dont have commands.

Here is an example of the output:

```
Admin - add, del, announce
Member - find
```

Desired output:

```
Admin - add, del, announce
Member - find
Banned
OhterGroup1
OhterGroup2
OhterGroup3
OhterGroup4
OhterGroup5
```

if you need more information about the tables there is a sample of it in here:
[MySQL query for multiple tables being secondary tables multiple items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472970/mysql-query-for-multiple-tables-being-secondary-tables-multiple-items/6473118#6473118)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `LEFT JOIN` to the `groups_commands` instead. Note how the `JOIN` to `commands` has also been moved in this query.

```
SELECT g.name, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c.name),'') AS commands
FROM site_access b
    INNER JOIN groups g 
        ON b.group_id = g.id
    LEFT JOIN group_commands gc
        INNER JOIN commands c 
            ON gc.command_id = c.id
        ON g.id = gc.group_id
WHERE b.site_id = 1
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER BY g.status ASC
```

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli works just fine, that was one good example of what I was just commenting on the other question about inner and left joins ;) now it became quite simple to understand it

Comment: Note that this with approach, the IFNULL is not necessary.

Comment: @JoshL: GROUP_CONCAT() will return NULL if no non-NULL values are found, so the IFNULL might still be desirable to convert those NULLs to empty strings.

Comment: @JoshL: Note that this question is tagged MySQL, not Oracle.